# ImportError: cannot import name 'KEYS' from 'pybliometrics

Tags: google-colaboratory, importerror, pybliometrics

I am using pybliometrics in googlecolab. I am using Scopus Api key.
Everything was working fine, but this week the following error appears:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'KEYS' from 'pybliometrics.scopus.utils.startup' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pybliometrics/scopus/utils/startup.py)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi & welcome to SO! This is more of a bug report than a question for how to do things. Would you mean leaving an issue on the package's GitHub page?

Comment: I had the same issue but then exited my python interpreter and returned and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when using  Jupyter Notebook.

I was able to solve it by using power shell (in anaconda).